# Is it possible to inject lines of code at specific positions through annotations

Tags: java, annotations

I want to inject some code through annotations in java. 
The plan is I have two methods beginAction() and endAction(). I want to annotate a  method such that before executing the statements in the method the beginAction() will be put and after finishing executing them the endAction() will be put automatically. Is it possible. If yes please suggest me how to do.

```
@MyAnnotation
public void myMethod(){
    // Statement 1;
    // Statement 2;
}
```

At runtime the beginAction() and endAction() should be injected in the method through the annotation. That is it should become like the following at runtime.

```
public void myMethod{
    beginAction();
    // Statement 1;
    // Statement 2;
    endAction();
}
```

Comment: You're looking for AspectJ.

Comment: Or Spring Interceptors ;)

Comment: Can we write directly our own code without using them.

Comment: No. We always need some libraries.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need aspects. AspectJ is the most popular library in this case. You can read more about it here: https://eclipse.org/aspectj/docs.php

And here's the example of such aspect in use:

*Class with intercepted method:*

```
public class YourClass {
    public void yourMethod() {
        // Method's code
    }
}
```

*Aspect itself:*

```
@Aspect
public class LoggingAspect {

   @Around("execution(* your.package.YourClass.yourMethod(..))")
   public void logAround(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
       System.out.println("Do something before YourClass.yourMethod");
       joinPoint.proceed(); //continue on the intercepted method
       System.out.println("Do something after YourClass.yourMethod");
   }

}
```

Comment: Thanks @Rozart for the support.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it using just plain Java. However, there is a Java-like language that does allow this. It's called [Xtend](http://www.eclipse.org/xtend/index.html). It compiles to Java, not bytecode, so it benefits from all the wonderful things your Java compiler does.

It started life as an Eclipse project, but is now also available for IntelliJ.

One of its many features is a thing called "Active Annotations". They do exactly what you're asking for: they allow you to participate in the code generation process, so you can insert your `beginAction()` and `endAction()` methods as you want.

See http://www.eclipse.org/xtend/documentation/204_activeannotations.html for more info on Active Annotations.